# Extjs 4 How to get id of parent Component?

Tags: extjs4

I have multiple fieldset. And have Button inside each fieldset in Extjs 4.
   I want to get fieldset id on the button click event, so that i can know from which      fieldset the button was clicked

How do i get this?

```
    {
     xtype:'fieldset',
     id:'fs1',
     items:[{
     xtype:'button',
     id:'b1',
     handler:function(){
       // here i want to get fieldset's id because because fieldset and button were added dynamically.
      }
     }]
    }
```

Thanks,
   Kunal

```
  Actual Code:

  Ext.define('My.Group',{   
xtype : 'fieldset',
 config: {
     title:'Group' + i.toString(),
     id : '_group' + i.toString()       
 },
     constructor: function(config) {
     this.initConfig(config);

   return this;
 },

collapsible : true,
frame : false,
boder : false,
items : [ {
xtype : 'button',
text : 'Add KeyWord',
id: 'btn',
width : 100,
handler : function(button,event) {

     var fieldset = button.findParentByType('fieldset');
     var fieldsetsID = fieldset.getId();

    console.log(fieldset);

    Ext.getCmp(fieldsetId).insert(2, rangeField);
    Ext.getCmp(fieldsetsID).doLayout();
}

 }, {
 xtype : 'button',
 text : 'Add Range Type',
 width : 100
} ]
});
```

and i am calling this function on button click

```
 handler : function() {
        i=i+1;
        var group = new My.Group({
            title:'Group' + i.toString(),
            id : '_group' + i.toString()                
        });

        console.log(group);
        Ext.getCmp('_aspanel').insert(i, group);                
        Ext.getCmp('_aspanel').doLayout();
```

Comment: i want to access fieldset's id through the button. because i have multiple fieldset. And i want to add somthing in a particular fieldset from which the button was clicked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've implemented **handler** properly.

`{
    xtype:'fieldset',
    id:'fs1',
    items:[{
        xtype:'button',
        id:'b1',
        handler:function(btn){
            // Retrieve fieldset. 
            var fieldset = btn.up('fieldset');
            // Retrieve Id of fieldset.
            var fieldsetId = fieldset.getId();
        }
    }]
}`

In that case try this:

`button.up("[xtype='fieldset']")`

Comment: Yeah, `Ext.AbstracComponnent.up()` uses a different way to look up components higher in hierarchy. I wonder if that would work while `findParentByType` does not.

Comment: Sure, it works, I've tested it and I'm using it while I develop in ExtJs4

Comment: That's great. I've tested the code in my answer, and it works, and I am too using it in my job, yet Kunal has some trouble with it.

Comment: Thanks Mchl and Zango. I have tried both of your code and its working fine sepreatly. but now i found that in my case the fieldset is not extending. when i access fieldset, i got this as undefined. i am putting my actual code. please help me what is wrong with this.

Comment: @Kunal I have same doubt, If you have chat  [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)

Answer (score 5):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
  var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
      items:  {
        xtype:'fieldset',
        id:'fs1',
        items:[{
          xtype:'button',
          id:'b1',
          handler:function(b,e){
            var fieldset = b.findParentByType('fieldset');
            var fieldsetID = fieldset.getId();
            console.log(fieldsetID);
          }
        }]
      },
      renderTo: document.body
  });
});
```

Notice, that once you have `fieldset` variable, you can actually add items to this container directly, without need to use its ID

Comment: i have tried this but i got following error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getId' of undefined

Comment: That's a bit strange. I've updated the code above. You can also try with `findParentByType('container')`.

Comment: Error is showing that fieldset is not defined, so its not working. i also tried with container but in that case i got Panel's id in which i have added the fieldsets.

Comment: Now it's really strange. That would mean your `Ext.form.FieldSet` is not extending `Ext.container.Container`... which it obviously should... Please write what exactly version of ExtJS you use. I'll try to get back to you in a few hours.

Comment: @Kunal: I've updated the code above with one that I've just tested in Ext 4.0.1 as well as 4.0.2. It works correctly in both. See if you can get it to work in a separate document. If yes, that would indicate something else is interfering with the code you provided. If no... well then I've no idea what's going on.