# how to get id of fieldset

Tags: extjs4

my question is similar to [Extjs 4 How to get id of parent Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691919/extjs-4-how-to-get-id-of-parent-component).

But i am looking solution for it. As the answer given in the question doesn't seems to be useful

In my case i m having button in my each fieldset and also i m creating these fieldsets dynamically which contain button inside it.

Now on click event of button which is inside fieldset i want to get its corresponding fieldset id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will return parent fieldset:
`button.up("[xtype='fieldset']")`

Answer (score 1):

Mahesh,

ACtully the problem in our case is , it is not extending the Ext.form.FieldSet.
So look this [Extjs 4 How to get id of parent Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691919/extjs-4-how-to-get-id-of-parent-component/6718080#6718080)

```
As Zango said, **button.up("[xtype='fieldset']")** will work for you.
```

Thanks,
Kunal