# How to get Active Fieldset Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala

I have multiple **field set** (up to 11), How to I get Active field set Id? already I Google it but Like [Extjs 4 How to get id of parent Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691919/extjs-4-how-to-get-id-of-parent-component) but it's not working.

```
<fieldset id="field_1">
.....
<button class="action-button" id="button1" >Next</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="field_2">
.....
 <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
<button class="action-button" id="button2" >Next</button>
<button class="action-button"  >Save&Exit</button>
</fieldset>

.....

<fieldset id="field_10">
.....
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `active` ?

Comment: May be `$(":input").on('focus',function(){ alert($(this).closest('fieldset').attr('id')) })`

Comment: Its working fine Thanks @RayonDabre